# google app - using template statemeant failed

Tags: google-apps

It does not run javascript instead of showing the code on webpage. Anyone can tell me why?

```
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('JavaScript').getContent(); ?>
```

I can confirm that JavaScript.html was created.

Comment: Is your javascript code in `JavaScript.html` between the  `<script></script>` tags? example: `<script>$(function() { //Code });</script>`

Comment: Yes. Can you tell me how to link another file in google app script?
It did not work for " <?!   ?>"  I have to write script and css in one file now.

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct syntax in your [printing scriptlet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#printing_scriptlets) The [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#separate_html_css_and_javascript) has an exmaple of HTML, CSS and JavaScript in Separated files, they create an `include` function in the `.gs`, but the syntax is the same:

```
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('JavaScript').getContent(); ?>
```

**Make sure that:**

- Your `JavaScript.html` contain `<script>` tags respectively, because they are HTML snippets and not pure .js files:

JavaScript.html

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    console.log('Page is loaded');
  });
</script>
```

- Your `doGet()` function returns an `HtmlTemplate` object using the [createTemplateFromFile(filename)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createtemplatefromfilefilename) function:

code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate();
}
```

Comment: how to link a css file?

Comment: Tha same way, but make sure your` Stylesheet.html` contain `<style>` tags, example:  `<style> p { color: green; } </style> `

Comment: <?!= include('CSS.html'); ?>   it did not work. The stament was shown on webpage instead of reading content of css.html. I can confirm that it has <style> tags.

Comment: Please update your question and add the code you're using to be able to detect the issue. The JavaScript now works?